# How does one type <C-menu> or <next> on a keyboard (in Emacs)?

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout, keyboard

I recently came across these two keybindings in someone else's config and haven't seen them before. I have a US qwerty keyboard, a Kinesis Freestyle Pro. I know where the control, `C`, key is, and I see a `Menu` key in the left auxilliary cluster of my keyboard, but when I ask Emacs, `C-h k`, to describe `C-menu` it says: `<C-linefeed>` is undefined. So the `Menu` key produces is `linefeed`? And, I don't know where the `<next>` key is, I can only assume it is the media next key?

Even better, how would I ask Emacs for these values? I know about `C-h k`, `describe-key`, but is there a way, something like `C-x 8` return that would show me all the keys I could use including odd ones like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably depends on your keyboard. I have a typical US PC keyboard. I don't know whether I have a `<menu>` key (for `C-<menu>`). But the `<next>` key is the key labeled **Page Down**.

To see how Emacs calls any given keyboard key, use `C-h k`. For example, if I use `C-h k` and hit the key labeled **Page Down**, Emacs describes what it calls key `<next>`.

Comment: Many keyboards have a <menu> key to the immediate left of the right control key - or thereabouts...

Comment: @NickD: As does my keyboard. But Emacs calls it `<apps>`. Is that the `Menu` key that OP meant? Maybe, but OP said that Emacs calls it `<menu>`. Whatever it is, `C-h k` should say (1) whether Emacs sees that key and (2) what Emacs calls it.

Comment: When I do `C-h k` on that key on my keyboard, my emacs says that  it is the <menu> button. Keyboard stuff is black magic.